# The difference between an apparent horizon and event horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

I'm currently writing a project on minimal surfaces and general relativity - however I don't understand the difference between the apparent and event horizon? They ultimately both seemed to be defined as observer-dependent horizons which act as a black hole threshold of which light can't escape once it has passed the horizon?

Can anyone clear the difference up?

Comment: Related: [Event horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon) and [Apparent horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_horizon)

Comment: How is the event horizon observer dependent!

Comment: By the way all your questions have the same format. "I am writing a project on...Can someone explain this to me?" They are not exactly homework questions, but it all seems very much of the type "Solve this homework problem for me". I think you are supposed to show more what you have done in attempting to find an answer.

Comment: I linked you to my dissertation and the series of related papers earlier, and this question is certainly answered therein.  Suffice it to say that the event horizon is decidedly not observer-dependent, while the apparent horizon is.